# How can I change a TEXT column name in a report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I'm creating reports based of custom objects and column name is bit too long to show on the report since i have dozens of column to show, Is it possible to change the report column names/headers without changing the field label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Nick Kahn you can achieve this by creating new report type Based on your required object while creating custom report type after you select your object display section called Fields Available for Reports in that section there is a option available called edit layout.

And in this layout you can create a new section and drag & drop fields and after you drag the required field in new section double click on the required field rename the field while displaying in reports.

For Reference:

[image: For section creation]

[image: For Field]

Comment: yep thats what i just read 1+

Comment: Pavan -- in your first sentence, I think you meant `custom report type`, not `record type`